# Multiple IP Camera Feeds On Same Webpage

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, ip-camera

I have 2 IP Cameras that have a internal server page (i.e. http:\192.168.1.10\video.html). This page receives jpeg images from the camera and auto-refreshes (loads) using javascript.

Source code from the `video.html`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>ipCam - JPEG Video</title>
    <style type='text/css'>
        html,body
        {
            background-color:white;
            color:black;
            font-family:arial;
            font-size:12pt;
        }
        a,a:visited,a:active
        {
            color:grey;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        a:hover
        {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        h1
        {
            background-color:black;
            color:white;
            padding:5px;
        }
        h2
        {
            background-color:lightgrey;
            padding:5px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function loadImage()
        {
            var now=new Date();
            document.getElementById('the_img').src='image.jpg?'+now.getTime();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id='the_img' src='image.jpg' onload='loadImage()' onerror='loadImage()'>
    <br><br>
    <a href='.'>Home</a>



</body>
```

What I would like to do is build a custom site that has both live feeds in it. I would prefer not to use `<iframe>`. I would rather use Javascript or something of the sort.

I have a basic understanding of HTML but very little Javascript experience. I can obviously look at the code a get a good idea of what is going on, but this has stumped me!

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that you could create a new HTML page (just copy the video.html from one of the cameras) on a local webserver and modify the script to include the ID of the `img` element you are updating and the IP address of the camera you are grabbing the feed from...something like this (which is set to automatically update the images every 4 seconds) -- (disclaimer: air code, not tested)

*Thanks @A.M.K. for fixing some stupid mistakes in my code:*

```
<script type='text/javascript'>         
    function loadImage(imgID, address)         
    {             
        var now=new Date();
        document.getElementById(imgID).src='http://' + address + '/image.jpg?'+now.getTime();
    }          

    setInterval(function() {
        loadImage("the_img_1", "192.168.0.1");
        loadImage("the_img_2", "192.168.0.2");
    }, 4000); //Interval to refresh at, in milliseconds
</script>
```

Then just setup another `img` tag to receive the image:

```
<body>
    <img id='the_img_1' src='http://192.168.0.1/image.jpg'>     
    <br><br>     
    <img id='the_img_2' src='http://192.168.0.2/image.jpg'>

    <a href='.'>Home</a>    
</body>
```

Note that you have two `img` elements now, each with a unique id which is fed to the function along with the IP address of the camera.

That may not work exactly in your situation, but that should give you an idea of how to accomplish it...

Comment: Don't forget a setInterval, it actually isn't in the original code, but it's probably a good idea.

Comment: That code won't work, the function can't be called from the page, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/FAfyu/ Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/FAfyu/2/

Comment: Umm, kind of nitpicking, sorry. But, your script tag closes before the JS ends....

Comment: @A.M.K - you are right, that's what I get for doing 10 things at once :) Thanks for the catch, revised my answer...third time the charm?

Comment: @A.M.K - lol, fixed that right as I saw your comment come through - think I'm done now :)

Comment: @nweston - are you using the most recent revision? A.M.K. helped me fix some mistakes which would've prevented the refresh...

Comment: @nweston - what browser are you running? Curious to see what the src attribute of the img tags are after the attempted refresh

Comment: Okay, please delete as many of your comments on this answer as you can to unclutter this thread. (hover over them and hit the red x)

Comment: @A.M.K There are random characters displayed on the page now: â€‹  any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
    // JS 9 CAM...

    //LAN.JS add http : // if you need

    var URL11='IP:Port/snapshot.cgi?&user=XXXXX&pwd=XXXXX';
    var URL12='IP:Port/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi?cmd=snapPicture2&usr=XXXXX&pwd=XXXXX';
    var URL13='IP:Port/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi?cmd=snapPicture2&usr=XXXXX&pwd=XXXXX';
    var URL14='IP:Port/snapshot.cgi?&user=XXXXX&pwd=XXXXX';
    var URL15='IP:Port/snapshot.cgi?&user=XXXXX&pwd=XXXXX';
    var URL16='IP:Port/snapshot.cgi?&user=XXXXX&pwd=XXXXX';
    var URL17='IP:Port/snapshot.cgi?&user=XXXXX&pwd=XXXXX';
    var URL18='IP:Port/snapshot.cgi?&user=XXXXX&pwd=XXXXX';
    var URL19='IP:Port/snapshot.cgi?&user=XXXXX&pwd=XXXXX';

    var L=window.location.search;
    L=L.substring(1,5);
    if(L=="")L=1;
    NewImage=new Image();
    var I=new Date().getTime();
    var imgW=320*L;

    function kamera1011(){document.getElementById("imgDisplay11").src=URL11+'&'+I++;};
    function kamera1012(){document.getElementById("imgDisplay12").src=URL12+'&'+I++;};
    function kamera1013(){document.getElementById("imgDisplay13").src=URL13+'&'+I++;};
    function kamera1014(){document.getElementById("imgDisplay14").src=URL14+'&'+I++;};
    function kamera1015(){document.getElementById("imgDisplay15").src=URL15+'&'+I++;};
    function kamera1016(){document.getElementById("imgDisplay16").src=URL16+'&'+I++;};
    function kamera1017(){document.getElementById("imgDisplay17").src=URL17+'&'+I++;};
    function kamera1018(){document.getElementById("imgDisplay18").src=URL18+'&'+I++;};
    function kamera1019(){document.getElementById("imgDisplay19").src=URL19+'&'+I++;};
    function kamera1020(){document.getElementById("imgDisplay20").src=URL20+'&'+I++;};
    function kamera1021(){document.getElementById("imgDisplay21").src=URL21+'&'+I++;};
    function kamera1022(){document.getElementById("imgDisplay22").src=URL22+'&'+I++;}

    <! HTML-index.htm >
<html>
<script language="JavaScript" src="js/lan.js"></script>
    <body onload="kamera1011(); kamera1012(); kamera1013(); kamera1014(); kamera1015(); kamera1016(); kamera1017(); kamera1018(); kamera1019();>

    <table border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">

    <tr>
    <td width="100%" align="center">

    </td>
    <td>
    <a href="index.htm">
    Updates Cams...
    </a>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
    <! Cam 1 >
    <img id="imgDisplay11" border="1" width="412" height="318" onload=setTimeout("kamera1011()",10) onerror=setTimeout("kamera1011()",100)>
    </td>

    <td>
    <! Cam 2 >
    <img id="imgDisplay12" border="1" width="412" height="318" onload=setTimeout("kamera1012()",10) onerror=setTimeout("kamera1012()",100)>
    </td>

    <td>
    <img id="imgDisplay13" border="1" width="412" height="318" onload=setTimeout("kamera1013()",10) onerror=setTimeout("kamera1013()",100)>

    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
    <img id="imgDisplay14" border="1" width="412" height="318" onload=setTimeout("kamera1014()",10) onerror=setTimeout("kamera1014()",100)>
    </td>

    <td>
    <! Cam 5 >
    <img id="imgDisplay15" border="1" width="412" height="318" onload=setTimeout("kamera1015()",10) onerror=setTimeout("kamera1015()",100)>
    </td>

    <td>
    <! Cam 6 >
    <img id="imgDisplay16" border="1" width="412" height="318" onload=setTimeout("kamera1016()",10) onerror=setTimeout("kamera1016()",100)>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
    <! Cam 9 >
    <img id="imgDisplay17" border="1" width="412" height="318" onload=setTimeout("kamera1017()",10) onerror=setTimeout("kamera1017()",100)>
    </td>

    <td>
    <! Cam 8 >
    <img id="imgDisplay18" border="1" width="412" height="318" onload=setTimeout("kamera1018()",10) onerror=setTimeout("kamera1018()",100)>
    </td>

    <td>
    <! Cam 9 >
    <img id="imgDisplay19" border="1" width="412" height="318" onload=setTimeout("kamera1019()",10) onerror=setTimeout("kamera1019()",100)>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table></html>
```

Comment: This doesn't really work well as an answer without a bit more explanation of how it improves on the OP's own code.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the following javascript in your page, changing the `interval` parameter to your like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        var interval = 5; //Interval in seconds, to retrieve images
        setInterval(function loadImage() {
            var now=new Date();
            document.getElementById('the_img').src='image.jpg?'+now.getTime();
        }, interval * 1000);
</script>
```

and in the html just insert the image wherever you want, like this:

```
<img id='the_img' src='image.jpg'>
```